# I don't know how to determine solutions of this differential equations... Some help plese!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

$$\big(1+y(x) y'(x)\big) y''(x)-\big(1+y'(x)^2\big) y'(x) = 0,\quad
y(0)=1,\quad 
y'(0)=1$$

The answer should be : $y(x)=e^x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y'=p$ and consider $p$ as a function of $y$. Then
$$
y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\,\frac{dy}{dx}=p\,\frac{dp}{dy}.
$$
Substituting in the equation results in
$$
(1+y\,p)\,p\,\frac{dp}{dy}-(1+p^2)\,p=0,\quad p(1)=1.
$$
Since $p\ne0$, we get the first order equation
$$
\frac{dp}{dy}=\frac{1+p^2}{1+y\,p}.
$$
An obvious solution is $p=y$, that is
$$
y'=y\implies y(x)=C\,e^x.
$$

But if you do not like this, consider $y$ as a function of $p$. The equation becomes
$$
\frac{dy}{dp}=\frac{p}{1+p^2}\,y+\frac{1}{1+p^2},\quad y(1)=1,
$$
a linear equation that can be solved.